# Azure Node JS Express web app facebook login

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have built a Node JS Express Blank Web App using Azure Web App service.
Then, I have configured Facebook Authentication and inputted my app ID and secret, etc.

Then, it allows the feature that when I accessed the web URL of my web app, it will see if the user is logged in and ask for their permission.
But, what if I want them to click the facebook login button and then login in using facebook and display their Username and icon?

[You can see the portal configuration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2ax7.png)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Try reading on the above maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, the following will help.

1) Set **Action to take when request is not authenticated** to `Allow Anonymous requests(no action)` in the Azure protal.

[image]

2) Add `authorization.json` file and define `URL Authorization Rules` in this file to restrict access to certain resources within your app. More details, please check out [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/11/17/url-authorization-rules/).

3) Add facebook login button into your home page, while the button is clicked redirect the user to:

```
https://<yourwebsitedomain>/.auth/login/facebook?post_login_redirect_url=/welcome
```

this will navigate the user to `/welcome` after logging in.

4) Once the user logged in, you are able to get authenticated user info with this endpoint: `https://<yourwebsitedomain>/.auth/me`.